# AWS IAM: Policy to allow users/role to create any resource, but only with specific tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM policy that will allow the user/role to create any resource (EC2, Redshift, RDS, etc.) - only if they provide certain pre-defined tags while creating them.

Steps followed so far:

1. Create an IAM Role: Let's call it role-XYZ
2. Attach AWS-Managed 'ReadOnlyPolicy' to this role - this will make sure the role has read-only access to all services
3. Create a new managed policy as follows. This will allow rest (including creation) of the actions based on a condition.

> 

```
{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VitalizeTagPermission",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:*",
                    "rds:*"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                        "aws:TagKeys": "ProjectCode"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

This does not work. The user is able to create the resource even without the ProjectCode tag. Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, tags are not universal. Each AWS service handles them in a different way and some API calls do not necessarily accept tags.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426761/aws-iam-policy-to-enforce-tagging